# Tomcat Deployment and Routing

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, tomcat

I feel like I’m attempting to accomplish a pretty simple task but I’m stumped. I’m attempting to use the Tomcat *Manage App* to deploy my app and then route my root domain name to point to that deployment.

Specifically, the app currently deployed at http://www.schmud.de/home/ should load when a person types http://www.schmud.de into their browser.

I tried deploying and [configuring this in CPanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications#3b126e96d1d2451194950af78d679f27) with no luck. It seems that the Tomcat *Manage App* interface or *Host Manager* interface is what I’m supposed to be use to configure my routing?

My `.htaccess` currently looks like this:

```
SetHandler jakarta-servlet
SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13
```

My `web.xml` is generated by Clojure.

Comment: checking in from your other question... Do you want to redirect from www.schmud.de to www.schmud.de/home/ ? How do you want your URLs to look in the end?

Comment: Why dont you use 'Redirect / /home' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it within the *Tomcat Web Interface* nor the `.htaccess` file. The user must have deeper access on a CPanel system.

Assuming that you have deployed your application as "**app**" and configured your `.htaccess` as I described above, here are the specific instructions I gave my root admin to solve the routing issue:

- open `/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/conf/server.xml`
- Under the `<Host>` tag add this:
- `<Context path="" docBase=“app” debug="0" reloadable="true" />`
- Restart the server
- Upon restart, http://domain.com/ should load my homepage (just as http://domain.com/app/ does now)